# Machine created as normal user isn't visible for administrator

Tags: docker, virtualbox

The problem was discovered with creating new machine in docker.

When you're creating new machine as administrator in Virtualbox, normal user can see machine inside Virtualbox, but status is alawys Stopped. You have to run VBox as administrator in order to check if this machine is in Running status.

Whats odd, this goes also in reverse way: when normal user creates VBox machine, VBox ran as administrator sees it only in Stopped status.

Why is this happening? What should I do in order to make sure that both machines are visible for normal and admin user?

This problems is happening also on Linux systems, but I'm working currently on Win7.

Workaround for this problem is stop machine as normal user, then start as admin - then admin can see it, but normal user not. If then normal user wants to see it, admin should stop it, and normal user start it.

Comment: Except the fact that your question is off-topic what are you actually talking about? Docker or VirtualBox? Would you mind sharing a little bit more information? What are your settings on the VM? What image do you use? Etc...

Comment: I guess this problem is more concerning VirtualBox, but because of this Docker is failing. Standard docker image, creating new machine with `docker-machine create --driver=virtualbox --virtualbox-host-dns-resolver= true default'. If you'll run this as admin, you will see it running on VBox (and docker) only as admin - the same as normal user.